# Have callback function for button while it is pressed on wp7 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

In Windows Phone 7 Silverlight is there a way to be able to have a button that while I have it selected it calls on a callback function.  Either that, or have to functions one for when the button is selected and one for when the button is released.  Any ideas as how to do this?

Note that I have already looked at the the toolkit, and the gestures they provide do not include this.

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't tested it so I don't know if it will work, but there is the `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` events, maybe you can use those!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, and to save some future soul the frustration of why the heck MS didn't implement this in the first place as part of their SDK...
I ended up solving this problem by using ManipulationStarted to record the start time, and ManipulationEnd to record the end time of the gesture, and a separate thread to keep track of the ticks in between.

Answer (score 0):

On `MouseLeftButtonDown` start a timer that will `Tick` until `Button` is released. Also, you have a control on timer tick `Interval`

Comment: Not that this is on the phone... there is no mouse, I believe.

Comment: `MouseLeftButtonDown` event is exists in WP7, but I checked and it don't raised on `Button`. So, `ManipulationStarted` is alternative that you can use as press event

Answer (score 0):

you could look at this in-depth article on gestures:

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-GestureService-in-depth--key-concepts-and-API

specifically the Tap and hold gesture might work for you.

These events would be applicable:
•GestureBegin

```
   The GestureBegin event. 
   public event EventHandler<GestureEventArgs> GestureBegin;
```

•GestureCompleted

```
   The GestureCompleted event. 
    public event EventHandler<GestureEventArgs> GestureCompleted;
```

Comment: As I said in my note, the gestures toolkit doesn't work.  Tap is just that, and hold basically just sends one single event after x amount of time that the button is held.  Not a continues delta.  Both the GestureBegin and GestureCompleted events no longer exist...  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create an action that is similar to the list item tilt effect. or like the video scrub bar. both of those operate when finger is down on the screen, then return to previous state when you remove your finger?

Comment: perhaps you could poll: TouchPanel.GetState()